# Frobenius determinant theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

Can anyone please recommend a paper or a book that gives a detailed proof of the Frobenius determinant theorem? I have read some few papers I saw online but their information are not sufficient for my understanding.Thanks.

Comment: Keith Conrad has a  [note](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/articles/groupdet.pdf) on his website about the origin of representation theory, including a list of references.